# Contents of the k03sendsigs file in ~/etc/rc0.d?

Tags: files

I accidentally overwrote the k03sendsigs file contents while modifying and wondered if anyone could post the contents of the file?  It's located in /etc/rc0.d/k03sendsigs

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `"apt-file search "sendsigs"` and look for the package that contains this file and reinstall the package